# Putty Configuration issue

Tags: putty

I am trying to configure putty appearance settings but I do not see any option to save other than OPEN. Included snap shot of putty session. Can anyone advise here if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

This button can be found under the session management options:

[image: PuTTY screenshot with red freehand circle indicating the "Save" button]

Make sure to select "Default Settings" before trying to save your changes.